# How to cast a List<MyModel> to List<object>

Tags: c#

I'm not sure if what I am trying to do is setup correctly so I am asking for help.

I have a base class, A,  that has a public virtual MethodA(...).
In Method A I have the following statement:

```
var recordToValidate = GetBulkRecordsToBeValidated(profileId);
< more code that uses recordToValidate >
```

In the base class A I define GetBulkRecordsToBeValidated as follows:

```
internal virtual List<object> GetBulkRecordsToBeValidated(int profileId)
{
   throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I have other classes that inherit from Class A (i.e. Class B inherits from Class A, Class C inherits from Class A, etc).

Each inherited class overrides the GetBulkRecordsToBeValidated which makes a call to the database to return the specific records for that entity.  Each entity returns a different model which is why in the base class I have the method return a List of object.

In Class B it looks like this:

```
internal override List<object> GetBulkRecordsToBeValidated(int profileId)
{
    return makes call to database which returns a List<ModelBRecords>
}
```

In Class C it looks like this:

```
internal override List<object> GetBulkRecordsToBeValidated(int profileId)
{
    return makes call to database which returns a List<ModelCRecords>
}
```

The problem is I am getting the following error in Class B and Class C on the return:

Cannot convert expression type System.Collection.Generic.List ModelBRecords  to return type System.Collection.Generic.List object

What do I need to do so I can return different list types to the call to GetBulkRecordsToValidate in Method A of the Base Class A?

Comment: What version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: @maksymiuk: [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/138661). The OP is asking about casting, but what he really needs is a generic base class.

Answer (score 2):

As a quick fix, use `.Cast<Object>.ToList()`.

However, you might want to consider making the base class generic like this:

```
public class A<T>
{
    public void MethodA()
    {
        List<T> recordToValidate = GetBulkRecordsToBeValidated(profileId);
        ....
    }

    internal virtual List<T> GetBulkRecordsToBeValidated(int profileId) // you might want to make this an abstract method instead of virtual
    {
        ....
    }       
}

public class C : A<ModelCRecords>
{
    internal override List<ModelCRecords> GetBulkRecordsToBeValidated(int profileId)
    {
        return makes call to database which returns a List<ModelCRecords>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create generic class

```
class A<T>
{
    public virtual List<T> GetBulkStuff() { throw new Exception(); }
}

class B : A<ModelBRecords>
{
    public override List<ModelBRecords> GetBulkStuff()
    {
        return base.GetBulkStuff();
    }
}
```